# Accessing Localstorage data from server in phone gap app

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, offline

I am creating a app for android which works in online as well as offline mode,
i have html page in my app which opens when the device is offline,from this page i want access data which is stored in localStorage from server in online mode, but when try to access that localStorage from my app it will return null value.
How we can access that value from my app.

Comment: var user = localStorage.getItem("username");

Comment: If you are in online read the data from server and put it into localstorage

Answer (score 0):

to put data in local storage

```
localStorage.setItem('username',value);
```

to get data from local storage

```
 var user = localStorage.getItem("username");
```

config.xml

```
<feature name="Storage" >
    <param
        name="android-package"
        value="org.apache.cordova.Storage" />
```

and dnt forget to include cordova.js in your page

Comment: still i am getting null value.